# is the clarity of using a 2d array worth the extra computational time required to search?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm pulling data from a csv and uploading it to a db, for some columns, only certain values should be inputted (or it'll break going through the rest of the system)
however users don't to write out the full input so will use "y" instead of "yes"

I wrote a function that takes an array of the possible inputs and what the correct output should be.
however, currently the array and function looks like this:

```
$this->acceptedInputMap = array (
    'yes' => 'yes',
    'y' => 'yes',
    'true' => 'yes',
    'no' => 'no',
    'n' => 'no',
    'false' => 'no',
    'unknown' => 'unknown',
    'unk' => 'unknown',
    '' => 'unknown'
);


//these are in the parents class------------------------------------

protected function useAcceptedinput()
{
    foreach ($this->columnData as $key => $element) {
        if ($this->isExpectedInput($element)) {
            $this->useMappedInput($key, $element);
        } else {
            $this->useColumnDefault($key);
        }
    }
}

protected function isExpectedInput($element)
{
    return array_key_exists(strtolower($element), $this->acceptedInputMap);
}

protected function useColumnDefault($key)
{
    $this->columnData[$key] = $this->defaultValue;
}

protected function useMappedInput($key, $element)
{
    $this->columnData[$key] = $this->acceptedInputMap[strtolower($element)];
}
```

I wanted to change this to use a different structure:

```
$this->acceptedInputMap = array (
    'yes' => array(
        'yes',
        'y',
        'true'
    ),
    'no' => array(
        'no',
        'n',
        'false'
    ),
    'unknown' => array(
        'unknown',
        'unk',
        ''
    ),
);
```

This is a lot clearer for future developers and would make it a lot easier to add more accepted inputs.
This also allows me to have the parent store some common acceted inputs, such as "yes", that can be pulled down for each column that requires it.

However, this is a 2d array, and attempting to find the value in the second dimension to map to the correct input is more computationally intensive.
Is the change worth it?
Also, in general, where do you draw the line on making it easier for the next dev, vs making it faster?

Comment: sorry, typo, changed it now, thanks.

Comment: It may look prettier, but surely you want the thing the user enters to be the Key, so its easily findable and the `value` is there and easily used to replace. Your pretty way makes it all so much more complicated

Comment: i would love it if users could enter the correct details, but when are users ever as helpful as that? :D. it's taking in files that are thousands of rows, so it's understndable that they might want to enter y instead of yes

Comment: My point was if the user enters `ye` when it should have been `yes` then you want `ye` to be the key of the array and not `yes` because you dont know to search the `yes` array to see if `ye` is one of the known errors that you can fix

Comment: also this is a simple example, there are others where there are 40 possible correct outputs, each with about 6 inputs, a 240 line array with no structure is pretty horrible for the next dev to deal with

Comment: Again, if you are not a human, you DO NOT KNOW that `y` should be converted to `yes`.... So the key to your array of "Things I can correct" need to be the thing that is in error i.e. the `y` and not the `yes`

Comment: _“where do you draw the line on making it easier for the next dev, vs making it faster?”_ - the first line is _always_, “does this _need_ to be made any faster?” If you don’t currently have any speed issues with the whole process, then there is little reason to optimize anything in that regard.

Comment: yes, thats why i was saying it would be a lot more computationally intensive, since it would involve searching the 2nd dimension of each array. (although technically its the same number of records that it'd need to search, maybe it wouldn't be too much more?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could organize the original array to make it more readable without sacrificing performance by adding comments or blank lines:

```
$this->acceptedInputMap = array (
    // yes --------
    'yes' => 'yes',
    'y' => 'yes',
    'true' => 'yes',

    // no ----------
    'no' => 'no',
    'n' => 'no',
    'false' => 'no',

    // unknown -----
    'unknown' => 'unknown',
    'unk' => 'unknown',
    '' => 'unknown'
);
```